# Finding a maximal orthonormal set in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthogonality

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be the banach algebra of bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$. If $e$ is a unit vector in  $\mathcal{H}$, is it possible to find unitary operators $U_n$ in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$ such that $U_n e$ form a maximal orthonormal set in  $\mathcal{H}$? I think I need to use the axiom of choice to show this, but cannot find a way. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just extend $e$ to an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ with $e_1=e$. There exist unitary operators $U_n$ such that $U_ne_1=e_n,U_ne_n=e_1$ and $U_ne_j =e_j$ for $j \notin \{1,n\}$. Of course $\{U_n e\} \equiv \{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: How can there exist such unitary operators?

Comment: If $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space H and $\{f_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis for another Hilbert space K and then there exists a unitary operatos $U:H \to K$ such that $Ue_n=f_n$ for all n. This is elementary: simply define $U(\sum a_n e_n)=\sum a_n f_n$ whenever $\sum a_n^{2} <\infty$ and verify that this is unitary.